# Finding specific services with specific startname

Tags: powershell, service

I m looking for a powershell one line script to find all the services that contain the word "Altiris" and service start name not equal 'localSystem'. Is the below a valid script for that purpose?

```
$Services = get-WMIObject -query "Select * from win32_service where name -contain 'Altiris' and startname -ne 'LocalSystem'"
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `-Contains` in WMI Query Language. The operators you are using are all PowerShell operators and the WQL operators are different.

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Service WHERE Name LIKE '%Altris%' AND StartName
<> 'Localsystem'"
```

For more information on WQL Operators, read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394605(v=vs.85).aspx